# Список для последовательного вызова методов

Tags: python, классы

Имеется скрипт (назовем его "главный", в котором создаётся некоторый экземпляр класса с атрибутами для работы его методов из некоего модуля (или библиотеки).

```
import foolib

attr1 = 4
attr2 = [5, 5, 3]
attr3 = 'foobar'

bar = foolib.Bar(attr1, attr2, attr3)

methods = [bar.method1, bar.method2, ..., bar.methodN]
result = ''

for method in methods:
    result += method()

print(result)
```

Класс содержит, например, 7-8 методов (не считая конструктора и т.п.), результатами выполнения которых является, например, строка. У класса есть атрибуты, которые используются теми или иными его методами, причем могут быть использованы как все сразу атрибуты, так и лишь некоторые.

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, attr3):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.attr3 = attr3
    
    def method1(self):
        # some actions using self.attr1, self.attr3 or other combinations and attributes
        ...
        return result
    
    def method2(self):
        # some actions using self.attr2, self.attr3 or other combinations and attributes
        ...
        return result
        
    def method3(self):
        # some actions using self.attr1, self.attr2 or other combinations and attributes
        ...
        return result
        
    ...
    
    def methodN(self):
        # some actions using attributes
        ...
        return result
```

В "главном модуле" производится последовательный вызов всех методов для получения данных.
**Вопрос заключается в следующем**: этично ли в данном случае создать список из методов класса, а затем при прохождении этого списка вызывать каждый метод в цикле при этом передав нужные им данные через атрибуты класса ещё при создании экземпляра класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да вы правильно заметили некоторую нелогичность в своем коде. Если вы измените количество или название методов в файле foolib, то надо будет помнить, что надо при этом поменять и список `methods` в основной программе. В питоне есть модуль `inspect`, который позволяет посмотреть, что находиться в модуле, классе или функции.
Мы можем получить все методы объекта `bar` с помощью `getmembers и ismethod`.

```
from inspect import getmembers, ismethod

import foolib

attr1 = 4
attr2 = [5, 5, 3]
attr3 = 'foobar'

bar = foolib.Bar(attr1, attr2, attr3)
tuple_methods = getmembers(bar, ismethod)
print(tuple_methods)
methods = [bar_method for name_method, bar_method in tuple_methods if not name_method.startswith('__')]

result = ''

for method in methods:
    result += method()

print(result)
```

---

```
[('__init__', <bound method Bar.__init__ of <foolib.Bar object at 0x000002B6118BAFD0>>),
('method1', <bound method Bar.method1 of <foolib.Bar object at 0x000002B6118BAFD0>>),
('method2', <bound method Bar.method2 of <foolib.Bar object at 0x000002B6118BAFD0>>),
('method3', <bound method Bar.method3 of <foolib.Bar object at 0x000002B6118BAFD0>>),
('methodN', <bound method Bar.methodN of <foolib.Bar object at 0x000002B6118BAFD0>>)]
```

Затем собираем из них нужный список и работаем с ним.